# Integral identity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, metric-spaces

Let $d$ the function defined as :

$$d(x,y)= {\left[\int_a^b {(g(t)-f(t))}^{2} \, dt\right]}^{1/2}$$

I must prove that d is a metric in $R^{n}$, the first three condition are trivial but the triangle  inequality I tried to prove from this equality:
$$
\left(\int_a^bf(t)g(t)\:dt\right)^2=\int_a^bf^2(t)\:dt\int_a^bg^2(t) \:dt-\frac1{2}\int_a^b\int_a^b (f(s)g(t)-g(s)f(t))^{2}\:ds \:dt
$$

I finally prove the Integral Cauchy inequality but how can I prove this equality, this equality was a hint from a book, so I need to prove it, but I stock with this someone can help me please.

I want to prove the Cauchy inequality in metric space but in the integral form in $R^n $ and the book hint me that equality (photo) to prove it but I do not know how to prove only the integral in the photo

Comment: Yea I edited, sorry

Comment: $\left(\int_a^b h(t) dt\right)^2 = \int_a^b \int_a^b h(s) h(t) ds dt$

Comment: A metric on what? (Note you don't want $d(x,y)$ above.)

Comment: I want to prove the Cauchy inequality in metric space but in the integral form in R^n and the book hint me that equality (photo) but I do not know how to prove only the integral in the photo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_a^b\int_a^b (f(s)g(t)-g(s)f(t))^{2}\:ds \:dt&=\int_a^b\int_a^b (f^2(s)g^2(t)+f^2(t)g^2(s)-2f(s)g(s)f(t)g(t))\:ds \:dt
\\
&=\int_a^bf^2(s)\:ds\int_a^bg^2(t) \:dt+\int_a^bf^2(t)\:dt\int_a^bg^2(s)\:ds
\\ &\:\:-2\int_a^bf(s)g(s)\:ds\int_a^bf(t)g(t)\:dt
\\
&=2\int_a^bf^2(t)\:dt\int_a^bg^2(t) \:dt-2\left(\int_a^bf(t)g(t)\:dt\right)^2
\end{align}
Thus
$$
\left(\int_a^bf(t)g(t)\:dt\right)^2=\int_a^bf^2(t)\:dt\int_a^bg^2(t) \:dt-\frac1{2}\int_a^b\int_a^b (f(s)g(t)-g(s)f(t))^{2}\:ds \:dt
$$
Note that 
$$
\int_a^b\int_a^b (f(s)g(t)-g(s)f(t))^{2}\:ds \:dt\geqslant0
$$
So Cauchy-Schwarz follows.

Comment: Hi Daniel, please how can show it: $\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(y)dydy=\int_{0}^{x}(x-y)f(y)dy$

Comment: Hi Daniel, plase can you guide us about https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384946/perfect-set-0-1#comment4917905_2384946